# asp.net Authentication access failed resetting by itself

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a login that uses the asp.net authentication features and will locks users out of the system if they type in their password incorrectly multiple times.

When the user incorrectly types in their password, the [AccessFailedCount] field increments by 1 every time (in the dbo.AspNetUsers table) as intended.

However, on their final try (say 5th) before the error message shows up on screen to show users that they've been locked out, the [AccessFailedCount] resets back to 0 which prevents me from seeing how many times that user account failed to login.

The code block that gets hit is as below:

```
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                var lockoutMessage = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LockoutMessage"];
                ModelState.AddModelError("", lockoutMessage);
                return View(model);
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please check your credentials and try again.");
                // Incorrect login info.
                return View(model);
        }
```

When the user incorrectly types in their password, the "Failure" case gets hit 4 times, then the "LockedOut' case gets hit and the [AccessFailedCount] gets reset to 0.

It seems to be happening somewhere in the PasswordSignInAsync method as the count is already set to 0 before the cases are hit.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour from happening (at all)? I would have suspected that if anything, the [AccessFailedCount] field should only be reset if the user successfully logs in, but it resets even when the user gets the error message saying that they can't login for a set period of time.

It looks like it's an in built feature of the asp.net authentication features but I am unsure how to prevent the [AccessFailedCount] field from being reset.

Answer (score 0):

When I started reading your question, my guess was that when a user types wrong password in, the 'AccessFailedCount' increases by 1 until it reaches a specific threshold say 5. Reaching to threshold it goes back to 0, reseted, and account is really locked.

Lockout is implemented by changing LockoutEndDateUtc. I recommend checking the exat value of the threshold number. Also keep an eye on LockoutEndDateUtc and LockoutEnabled fields.

Comment: Oh right, that's interesting. I haven't read anywhere on how the logic for AccessFailedCount works so if that's the case it looks like it's done that by design. I guess that means you can't really find out how many times a user has failed logging in unless you set the threshold to something like 1000 or so, and that you can't really see how many times an account has failed to login without using any external methods?

Comment: @intrepidexplorer As far as I know you are correct. But it's just a guess. Someone should provide a reference to fail count mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

`AccessFailed` resets to `0` at the end of a 'fail' cycle by design.

Once the maximum number of attempts has been reached, `AccessFailed` resets to `0` and `LockoutEndDateUtc` is set again. You only have access to the number of failed attempts within each `fail` cycle.